# I want to create a quiz module. Which kind of database I should use SQL(Postgres) Or NoSQL(MongoDB)

Tags: sql, nosql

I want to create a quiz module. 
It will have tables like quiz details, quiz question and quiz answer.
Which kind of database I should use SQL(Postgres) Or NoSQL(MongoDB).
If NoSQL joins will be the problem then I have to store question and answers in one collection.
To keep question and answers (options) in the same collection is good approach?

Answer (score 0):

For Quiz module, You will not get concurrent update\delete request for the same row. so i suggest to use NoSQL.
For NoSQL, you can use Question module as a separate collection and answer Collection with reference of Question's object_id. so structure will be normalized in good way.